# Grep | cut not finishing process

Tags: process, grep, cut

I'm trying to parse some text from a text file in Linux using the following command:

```
grep "x" | cut -d ":" -f 2 EthernetData1.txt
```

Everything seems to be working fine as in the display I can see the expected result but the process does not finish so I can't execute another command without clicking [Ctrl + c].

The file is quite big but the proccess seems to reach the end of it.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean

```
grep "x" EthernetData1.txt | cut ...
```

i.e. you need to give your input file to grep not cut.